# Hierarchical Metadata - Filter List of Cities Based on Chosen Country

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store, cascading-dropdown

Cascading drop downs have been a challenge in previous versions of SharePoint and I'm just wondering if this is supported in SharePoint Online. We have a Term Set with the structure shown below. As you can see, Canada has different cities than USA

[image]

Is there anyway to create cascading fields that are filtered based on the parent selection? If USA is chosen as a Country, then the Canadian cities should not be available in the child field. But as of now, they are completely independent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent with metadata fields would be to use one field, instead of a field per level. So, create a field named something like "location", which would point to the metadata term set as its source. A user would use the tree structure to drill down to the desired city. The OOB list filter will allow you to filter at any level. So a filter on USA would display all records where the user selected USA, or any city in the US.

If you need two separate fields, then refer to Susan's answer, and configure something in PowerApps. (InfoPath is the older tool. It's great, but not recommended at this point).

Comment: That makes sense unless there are 2 cities with the same name in both countries. How do you decipher then?

Comment: The metadata field has an option to display the full path of the item, so : USA:Paris. Though, last time I tried that, it broke the list filter....(this issue was in a modern view. If you're in classic, it may not be an issue.)

Comment: Showing the full path would clarify those instances. I'll test it out thanks @Mike2500

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you posted is still realistic and achievable in sharepoint online. Almost nothing has changed in the term store management.

To be able to achieve it in other ways is

Infopath (see this video with a good example albeit much more simple than your scenario https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HnLhXVQf-M&t=2s). Might that Infopath is the old way to do things.

Powerapps (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wfSAsU93b4)